# JavaScript code printing extra line (undefined) in output

Tags: javascript, constructor

need help with this code. What am I doing wrong?

Problem:
Create 10 cars, where each car has a color and number. The cars should be numbered in order from 0 to 9. The cars from 0 to 4 should be colored "green" and the cars from 5 to 9 should be colored "blue". Place the cars in order in an array called carGarage.

Guideline:
To avoid duplicate code when creating 10 separate cars, first first create a constructor function Car that takes color and number parameters and sets them to this.color and this.number. Then create 10 cars and place them in a carGarage array.

```
// create a car constructor function
var Car = function(color, number) {
    this.color = color;
    this.number = number;
}
// create a carGarage array
var carGarage = [10];
// create a loop that creates cars and places them in carGarage
for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    var color, number;
    i <= 4? color = 'green': color = 'blue';
    number = i;
    var newCar = new Car(color, number);
    carGarage.push(newCar);

}
// test code
for (var i = 0; i < carGarage.length; i++) {
   car = carGarage[i];
   console.log(car.color + " car #" + car.number);
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
green car #0
green car #1
green car #2
green car #3
green car #4
blue car #5
blue car #6
blue car #7
blue car #8
blue car #9
```

**Actual Output**

```
undefined car #undefined
green car #0
green car #1
green car #2
green car #3
green car #4
blue car #5
blue car #6
blue car #7
blue car #8
blue car #9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the key:

```
var carGarage = [10];
```

You've initialized array with one element - `10`, not array of length 10. You have to change it to:

```
var carGarage = [];
```

So you initialize empty array.

You had 2 times `undefined` because both `10.color` and `10.number` aren't defined.

Comment: Thanks man! I knew i could declare just an empty array to start with and that would work, but then I thought since I already knew I had just 10 definite elements why not try? But JS is weird, it just wouldn't work, thanks, I'll accept it.

Comment: Sure, in other languages square brackets are used to specify array length. (C#)